# Bad to learn XNA without an amazing foundation on C#?

Tags: xna, c#

I've been going though Head First C#, and enjoying it's style of teaching.
But I'm into this as a hobby for now, and I'm itching to learn more about games, so I've been diving into Learning XNA 4.0 as well.

Is this a bad idea? Is my lack of C# gonna harm adapting it? 'cause as of now, it feels much more rewarding.
Between that and http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/2d-tutorials, I've been having more "fun" drawing sprites and animations than making calculators.

Comment: if people always waited to make things in framework/sdk/api X Y or Z until they were masters of the language they were using, nobody would ever write anything! write your game. have fun. explore language features, learn xna, just go already.

Answer (score 4):

Why would it be? The best way to learn is to get your hands dirty. Doesn't matter what you are doing you are always going to get better.

Just start small, don't overwhelm yourself with trying to have the most efficient and correct code. As you code and code, you will learn whats right and wrong.

Also, don't be afraid to ask many questions. (at the same time, don't forget to use Google).

Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

It depends. If you lack programming skills at all, it can be bad. Better learn some basis of it first, then jump into game programming. I didn't know nothing of C# when I started coding with XNA, it was very easy to get everything, but I already had 2 or 3 years of programming skills, with C/C++, VB.NET and Delphi...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, what your doing is the best way to learn.  You get all the fun of making something interactive right away, while learning new concepts of a programming language.  Xna was how I came to learn about C#.  Before that I had a beginners knowledge of C/C++.  But now I must admit that I'm not a fan of C++ and much prefer the managed environment.

Bottom line, your doing just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have extensive knowledge on C# nor even Java when I started using XNA. At best, I actually just had an equivalent of a person who just finished beginning Java course knowledge level-wise. But because of this experience in XNA, I actually learned a lot more and it's actually been helping in my courses at school.

Overall what I'm saying is that you'll learn more as you program on it. If you find that you don't know how to implement a feature or how to tackle it, google searching helps. In the end, all I can see when you try to use other things (in this case, XNA) is that you learn more. The more you know and experience, the better you are as a programmer.